# Configure webpack production build

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I need to use production build with Webpack. If I visit my site now in production icon is having red background which means it's not using production

When I do npm run build, it says **npm ERR! missing script: build**

How can I adjust webpack so I can make a production build and make my app faster?

Here is my webpack config:

```
 const webpack = require('webpack');

const config = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.js'],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 8080,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        API_KEY: 'API_KEY',
        GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY: 'GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY',
        GOOGLE_GEOLOCATION_KEY: 'GOOGLE_GEOLOCATION_KEY',
      },
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css',
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
         API_KEY: 'API_KEY',
         GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY: 'GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY',
         GOOGLE_GEOLOCATION_KEY: 'GOOGLE_GEOLOCATION_KEY',
         NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production') // <--- this set everything to use production.
      },
    }),
  ],
```

Comment: thanks, is npm start now going to make a production build?

Comment: This is what I get when I click on dev tools extension: The React build on this page includes both development and production versions because dead code elimination has not been applied correctly. 

This makes its size larger, and causes React to run slower. 

Make sure to set up dead code elimination before deployment